# why i m gettin null from props in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

> here is my parent component from where i m passing props to a child
> component but i m getting null value at my child component i really
> unable to figure out where is problem here is my parent component:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-if="loading">
        <SfLoader :loading="loading" />
      </div>
      <div v-else>
    <CustomProductCard :product="product" />
        

      </div>
    </div>
  </template>  
<script>
import {usePageStore} from '~/stores/page'
import { useProduct } from '~/composables';
import { onMounted,ref } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import CustomProductCard from '~/components/CustomProductCard.vue'
import {SfLoader} from '@storefront-ui/vue'
 
export default{
    components:{
        CustomProductCard,
         SfLoader
    },
    setup(){
        const {routeData}  = usePageStore();
        const {getProductDetails,loading} = useProduct();

const product = ref('')

        const productParams = {
    filter: {
      sku: {
        eq: routeData.sku,
      },
    }
  };
  onMounted(async() => {
    const data = await getProductDetails(productParams);
    product.value = data.items?.[0]
  })
  console.log(product,"props value")
  return {
     product,
     loading
   }
    }
}
</script>
```

> here i m passing props to CustomProductPage
> here is child component where i m recieving this pros:

```
<template>
    <div class="custom_product-card" >
        <div class="custom_product-data" >
            <SfImage />
            <div class="custom_product-description" >
                <div>
                    //heading and desscription goes here
                </div>
                //sf select goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom_product-actions-container" >
            //price goes here
            <div class="product-price-container" >
                <div class="product-cart-actions">
//all the rating goes here
                </div>
            </div>
                            //add to cart action

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {
    SfImage,
    SfRating,
    SfSelect,
    SfAddToCart,
    SfPrice,
    SfHeading
}
from "@storefront-ui/vue";
export default {
    components: {
        SfImage,
    SfRating,
    SfSelect,
    SfAddToCart,
    SfPrice,
    SfHeading
    },
    props: {
    product: { 
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
},
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.product)
  }  
}
</script>
```

> so tell me why im getting null in console???

Comment: When you add ```v-if``` in *CustomProductCard*, what will happen or what it return? ```<CustomProductCard v-if="product" :product="product" />```

Comment: is it possible that you use AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Because your define const product = ref(''), if you want to get the product's value after the getProductDetails request completed,you need add a watch function

```js
import {
  watch
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
setup(props) {
  console.log(props.product)
  watch(() => props.product, () => {
    console.log(props.product)
  })
}
```

Comment: no i dont think so i need that...

Answer (score 0):

please check that product is available or not inside the  onMounted() like this:

```
onMounted(async () => {
      const data = await getProductDetails(productParams);
      product.value = data.items?.[0];
// check whether the data is there or not.
      console.log(data.items)
// if the data.item is not null, set the product using the this.$set method.
});
```

if the data.items is there it means product is available. Please try set method to set the product accordingly.
I am happy to look forward on this.

Comment: yes i checked it multiple time there is data but its not being passed through props

Comment: use the set methods and try this:
onMounted(async () => {
      const data = await getProductDetails(productParams);
// check whether the data is there or not.
      console.log(data.items)
// if the data.item is not null, set the product using the this.$set method.
product.value = { ...data.items?.[0] };
});